# Apache Ant is not able to find environment variables from Windows

Tags: ant

I have an ant build file in which I am trying to use an executable referenced in an environment variable, but Ant is not able to find it.

I echoed the value of the PATH variable and find that it is not actually getting anything. I am not sure why.

Below are the code sample and output.

Ant build file:

```
 <target name ="cmd-local">
    <echo message="$PATH is set to = ${PATH}" />
    <echo message="%PATH is set to = %PATH%" />
    <exec executable="cmd.exe">
        <arg line="/c echo %PATH%" />  
     </exec>
 </target>
```

Output:

```
[echo] $PATH is set to = ${PATH}
[echo] %PATH is set to = %PATH%
[exec] C:/Users/user1/Application/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/..
```

I am not sure why the first two are not printing anything.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that Ant doesn't import the environment into properties by default.  You have to ask it do that, and specify a prefix like:

```
<property environment="env" />
```

That will load environment variables into properties with names like `env.PATH`, hence you would access `PATH` with something like:

```
<echo message="$PATH is set to = ${env.PATH}" />
```

In Ant there's nothing special about Windows-style environment references like `%PATH%`, they are just treated as literal strings.

Comment: I tried as you mentioned.. directly copy pasted both of your line into my `build.xml` . but still it is not working... giving the below output  `[echo] $PATH is set to = ${env.PATH}`

Comment: same with env.PROGRAMDATA

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue, you should consider trying this (case-sensitive)

```
<echo message="$PATH is set to = ${env.Path}" />
```

This worked for me (on ant 1.9.5)